# How to obtain compilation classpath during annotation processing?

Tags: java, maven, classpath, annotation-processing

My attempt was

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] currentClassPath = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
String[] classPathStrings = Arrays.stream(currentClassPath).map(url -> {
    try {
        return Paths.get(url.toURI()).toAbsolutePath().toString();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(classPathStrings));
```

in the annotation processor's `process()` method body. But it outputs only
`[C:\Program Files\Maven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar]`

Instead of the dependencies of the processed project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's enough to use `getClass().getClassLoader()`. `getClass()` in the annotation processor context.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but after using this in my `AnnotationProcessor` I still get the classpath of the project doing the processing, not the processed project. Can you expand on this answer a bit?

Answer (score -1):

I think to load project classes during annotation-processing is not a good idea. Have in mind that creating classes is what you ar doing. So may be the classses are not available or using the class-laoder will slow down the compilation process